# IIS 8.5 Multiple sites on localhost with unique root directory

Tags: windows-8.1, iis, iis-8

I would like to create 3 different sites on my dev PC each with its own root directory which running different version of PHP
And I would like to have unique domain for them

Lets say my Default Website would be localhost with * :80 and * :443 binding (this is running PHP 5.6.2 x64) (Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot)

The second site would be localsecure with * :444 binding (this would running PHP 5.4.34 x86) (Path: C:\inetpub\wwwsecure)

The third site would be localold with * :81 binding (this would run PHP 5.3.29 x86) (Path: C:\inetpub\wwwold)

I tried to set up the three site with the bindings above and than added 127.0.0.1:81 and :444 to my hosts file with the desired name but I only get Page Can't be displayed error,
and of course it works if I type in 127.0.0.1:444 or localhost:444

How can I set up these three sites?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out. I add this answer because it could help others who are trying to do something like this

So first of all I realised how stupid I was because you can not define port number in the hosts file.

Than I edited my hosts file like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 localsecure
127.0.0.1 localold
```

After this I edited the bindings in IIS like this

```
Default Website: http: * :80 localhost
Default Website: https: * :443 localhost
Secure Website: https: * :443 localsecure
Old Website: http: * :80 localold
```

And of course in the PHP Manger I set the desired PHP version

Now it works as expected

I hope it will help someone.